# How to bind from view to model in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want upgrade the variable in my `contact.ts` by getting from my `contact.html`

#### contact.ts

```
@autoinject
export class ContactList {

  @bindable page;
  pageslist:any[];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, ea: EventAggregator) 
  { 
    this.page=1; //default page 
    this.pageslist=[1,2,3,4];

  }

   async attached() {
    console.log(this.apiGet+'page='+this.page+'count='+this.count)
   }
}
```

#### contact.html

```
<ul class="pagination" repeat.for="p of pageslist" bindable="page">
  <li>
    <a href="#" value.bind="p" click.delegate="go()">${p} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the `page` value based on what item of `pagesList` is clicked.
 For example if I click on the `pageList` of `2`, I want to append the `page` value in the `contact.ts` to `2`.

Anyone know how to bind the page when link is clicked?

Comment: `this.pageslist=[1,2,3,4];` in the class definition is not working. should be `pageslist=[1,2,3,4];`. also: `bindable="page"` on the `ul` don't do anything. `a` tag don't have `value` to bind to. I would use a nested router with the page number as parameter, or drop the `a` tag and use regular click on div..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<ul class="pagination" repeat.for="p of pageslist">
  <li>
    <a href="#" click.delegate="select(p)">${p} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then in your viewmodel:

```
public select(pagenumber) {
  this.page = pagenumber;
}
```

---

I'm assuming this is a page-selection component which requires styling, but if you need a similar functionality without the need for specific styling, you should use a `<select>` component like so:

```
<select value.bind="page">
  <option repeat.for="p of pageslist" model.bind="p">
    ${p}
  </option>
</select>
```

I would recommend this option if you don't need the styling since it uses a native HTML `<select>` element, which is exactly the behaviour you're trying to achieve.